# Out of all the medical imaging radionuclides, why is technetium-99m the most common?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering, imaging, medical-physics

There are medical tracers like Xe-133, I-131 etc.(what are some other ones?), but why is Tc-99m the most common (most suitable)?

Answer (score 2):

Technetium-99m is in many ways the perfect candidate for general-purpose imaging. It has:

- A short radioactive half-life and a short biological half-life as well, so the overall radiation dose to the patient is small
- Not *so* short of a half-life that it becomes too inconvenient
- A benign decay chain: it decays only to technetium-99, which has a very long half-life and the same chemical properties as the metastable isomer. The little bit that does further decay (to ruthenium) is then stable
- Its decay gammas are readily detectable and not accompanied by any other radiation
- No alpha or beta radiation (which are far more harmful biologically)

Some other common imaging radioisotopes are used for more specialized tests:

- Xe-133 is a gas, so it can be used to image the lungs by inhalation
- PET scans use biologically active molecules (usually some sugar with a carbon-12 replaced by carbon-11) to indicate what areas are most metabolically active, since excessive metabolic activity is a sign of cancer

Comment: Non-PET scans can also use biologically active molecules, and conversely, and conversely, PET scans can use biologically-inactive molecules - they just need those molecules to have isotopes which emit positrons (or actually, pairs of gammas in opposite directions, which is what you get from positrons when they encounter electrons).

Answer (score 0):

the gamma ray decay product is easily detected and relatively non-deadly, the material itself is easily prepared, and it has a relatively short half-life which makes it convenient as a tracer in biological systems.